# motion detector clcks but no light

Tags: wiring, lighting, motion-sensor

I'm trying to install a motion detector in a circuit with 4 halogen spot bulbs and no other switches. There used to be a regular switch before, so I know the spot bulbs work. When I pass in front of the motion detector, I can hear the click from the relay but the lights don't go on.

Below is picture of the wiring, these are the same wires that were connected to the old regular switch.
[image: picture of wiring]

I tried to switch the black and the gray wire but then there was no click from the relay nor did the lights go on. 
Did I make a mistake with the wiring or is my motion detector broken?

EDIT: picture of the old wiring with the regular switch (works fine):
since I can only post 2 links; the gray wire goes in a hole at the top, there
are no symbols on the top and there is only one hole.

[image: old wiring bottom]

Comment: Using the manual control on the switch can you turn on the light.

Comment: Manual control also does not turn on the light

Comment: Do you have a picture of the old switch wiring?

Comment: I edited the post with an extra picture

Comment: Is the old switch just a plain on/off switch or is it something else?  Any part numbers on the old switch.  Seeing three wire locations on the switch is usually found on lighted switches, three ways or electronic controlled.  A single wall switch would expect the neutrals to be wire-nutted, with only the hot and controlled wires to the switch.    If you have a volt meter or AC tester have you identified the hot wire is the black wire?

Comment: You sure there isn't some override setting on your motion detector? It may be firing the relay but if there's an override then power won't get to the output leg.

Comment: @spicetraders It's a plain on/off switch, I created a zip with additional pictures -> [link](http://gofile.me/2x6LP/X8aLkXs6i). I do live in Belgium and from what I read on wikipedia american three-way switches are called two-way switches in Europe. I sadly don't have a voltage meter.

Comment: @carl there is no override as far as I can see, nor is there any mention of it in the manual, I set everything up exactly as mentioned in the manual.

Comment: The reason for so many questions is the old switch having three terminals.  and four wires plus a ground.  What I would normally expect would be like seen in these links  [switch at end power to light](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3f/82/49/3f82496ac024a0841dc7dd4be7fdb166.jpg)  [simple view](http://www.vesternet.com/media/wysiwyg/Application_notes/APNT-23_2-wire-Lighting.png)  So I am concerned if the blues are neutrals or not?   If they are neutrals why connected in the old switch?  If the feed was in the switch location then normal is to wire-nut the neutrals in the box. US

Comment: You can try the motion switch in another wall switch location if possible, this if it works elsewhere will tell for certain that it is good.  But not necessarily tell if it is bad.  I am also curious if you leave the two blue as they are on the motion switch (basically using the switch to tie them together).  And move the black and gray to the old switch locations seeing if the old switch turns on the light.  I am still trying to make sure the two blue are neutrals and the black is the hot.

Comment: I tried a bunch of things, now it doesn't even click anymore, so it's probably broken. My uncle will come by tomorrow to see if he can make it work, I'll let you know what happened.

Comment: I screwed open the motion detector and found that the capacitors near the IR-sensor were sort of molten, which is probably the reason why it didn't click anymore. I also found that on another circuit-board inside, 2 conductors of different capacitors were  touching, which may be the original cause why the light wasn't working.